# Powershell endinvoke function gets stuck under heavy load

Tags: c#, multithreading, powershell

My application is written in c# and uses Powershell class of .net library. It is multi-threaded and can execute a bunch of powershell scripts simultaneously on a runspacepool.
I use a runspacepool size of 100. Before the execution of each script I create a session to the target computer, by using the code below.
I use BeginInvoke to start execution in a pipeline  and end-invoke to get the results, which include the session.

```
    ps = PowerShell.Create()
    var sessionScript = new PSCommand();
    sessionScript.AddCommand(New-PSSession);
    sessionScript.AddParameter("ConnectionUri",  "http://192.xxx.x.xxx:5985";);
    sessionScript.AddParameter("AllowRedirection");
    var sessOpt = new System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSSessionOption();
    sessOpt.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0, 120000);
    sessOpt.CancelTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0,120000);
    sessionScript.AddParameter("SessionOption", sessOpt);
    var cred = new PSCredential(uName, password);
    sessionScript.AddParameter("Credential", cred);
    ps.Commands = sessionScript
    ps.RunSpacePool = mypool  ## size 100 created earlier
    asyncResult = ps.BeginInvoke();  
    resultsOut = ps.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
```

All is fine when I keep my number of parallel executing sessions below 100. Once in a while when I hit 100 and above, I notice one or two threads (.net tasks) just getting stuck. I did some debugging and realized that the thread was getting stuck for EndInvoke. Even after a week the call just didn't return and the thread was still alive.

So, I replaced execution code by adding a Timer to this operation

```
    Timer taskTimer = new Timer(TaskHitTimeout, null , 120000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    asyncResult = ps.BeginInvoke(); 
    while (true)
            {
                if (asyncResult.IsCompleted || this.isCancelled)
                    break;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

    if (!this.isCancelled)
         resultsOut = ps.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
```

and in the TimerHandler I set isCancelled to True

```
     private void TaskHitTimeout(Object statusCode)
     { this.isCancelled = True;}
```

This did fix my problem. But I would like to understand why the call to EndInvoke just doesn't return. Is there anything else I can do to improve this. And If anyone else has seen a similar issue.